# Transforming a PNG from RD_new to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, wgs84, png

I got the request to transform a PNG in RD_new to WGS84. Is this possible?

I was thinking of changing the accompanied world file its coordinates. I do not think it is possible to load in a png in a transformation function right?

I normally would use spTransform from RStudio for it but I am expecting it wont work.

Comment: There is an xml doc type accompanied with the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GDAL, you can reproject the png with:

```
galwarp -s_srs epsg:28992 -t_srs epsg:4326 source.png dest.tif
```

If you want a png file as result, you have to use gdal_translate in a second step:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG test.tif dest.tif dest.png
```

Comment: I am sure this will work but I do not understand above lines of text. Probably that is for the command prompt right? I am not so familiar with working with the command prompt, prefer to stay within my working environment like RStudio.

Comment: Yes, it is for command line. But you can do the same with QGIS which is for free too.